# XMLHttpRequest and Chrome developer tools don't say the same thing

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I'm downloading a ~50MB file in 5 MB chunks using XMLHttpRequest and the Range header. Things work great, except for detecting when I've downloaded the last chunk.

Here's a screenshot of the request and response for the *first* chunk. Notice the Content-Length is `1024 * 1024 * 5` (5 MB). Also notice that the server responds correctly with the first 5 MB, and in the Content-Range header, properly specifies the size of the entire file (after the `/`):

[image: first chunk]

When I copy the response body into a text editor (Sublime), I only get 5,242,736 characters instead of the expected 5,242,880 as indicated by `Content-Length`:

[image: actual length]

Why are 144 characters missing? This is true of every chunk that gets downloaded, though the exact difference varies a little bit.

However, what's especially strange is the *last*  chunk. The server responds with the last ~2.9 MB of the file (instead of a whole 5 MB) and apparently properly indicates this in the response:

[image: last chunk]

Notice that I am requesting the next 5 MB (even though it goes beyond the total file size). No biggie, the server responds with the last part of the file and the headers indicate the actual byte range returned.

But does it really?

When I call `xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")` with Javascript, I see a different story in Chrome:

[image: Chrome dev tools don't agree]

The XMLHttpRequest object is telling me that another 5 MB was downloaded, beyond the end of the file. Is there something I don't understand about the `xhr` object?

What's even *weirder* is that it works in Firefox 30 as expected:

[image: Firefox XHR works]

So between the `xhr.responseText.length` not matching the `Content-Length` and these headers not agreeing between the `xhr` object and the Network tools, I don't know what to do to fix this.

What's causing these discrepancies?

**Update:** I have confirmed that the server itself is properly sending the request, despite the overshot Range header in the request for the last chunk. This is the output from the raw HTTP request, thanks to good 'ol `telnet`:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.4.5
Date: Mon, 14 Jul 2014 21:50:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 2987360
Last-Modified: Sun, 13 Jul 2014 22:05:10 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "53c30296-2fd9560"
Content-Range: bytes 47185920-50173279/50173280
```

So it looks like Chrome is malfunctioning. Should this be filed as a bug? Where?

Comment: xhr.responseText.length is the # of chars in your response, not the #of bytes indicated in the Content-Length headers. some unicode chars (or binary bits coerced into unicode) use more than one byte per char. chrome might 2nd-guess invalid range headers (like ones that overlap the file end), as may firefox, but only one approach (ff) seems to be working for your case. fix the REQUEST headers and try again.

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. See my update. I ran the request in telnet directly and the raw output from the server is as expected, meaning (I think?) that Chrome must be malfunctioning when making the XMLHttpRequest or something...

Comment: i'm suggesting chrome might be doing something special, not show here, by internally tying the request to the response. it appears the output from the server is fine, but chrome might also consider the input from the request (specifically range 0-52/50), which told it to expect more. sometimes being smart is dumb when you're a browser.

Comment: @dandavis I think I see what you're saying, that Chrome might be assuming something it shouldn't. But... the input/request doesn't include the total file size though: only the response's Content-Range has that.

Comment: all i'm saying is that the Range request header (the 0-5242879 one) you show in your first screenshot might be fooling chrome. why you reply every time about the response i don't know, but i would try changing the request if i were you...

Comment: @dandavis You're probably right. Anyway, I've changed the request header so it never exceeds the file size and now it's working. Thanks! I'll leave the question open though until someone has a more conclusive answer.

Answer (score 6):

The main issue is that you are reading binary data as text. Note that the server responds with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` which doesn't specify the encoding explicitly - in that case the browser will typically assume that the data is encoded in UTF-8. While the length will mostly be unchanged (bytes with values 0 to 127 are interpreted as a single character in UTF-8 and bytes with higher values will usually be replaced by the replacement character �), your binary file will certainly contain a few valid multi-byte UTF-8 sequences - and these will be combined into one character. That explains why `responseText.length` doesn't match the number of bytes received from the server.

Now you could of course force some specific encoding using [`request.overrideMimeType()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType%28%29), ISO 8859-1 would make sense in particular because the first 256 Unicode code points are identical with ISO 8859-1:

```
request.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

That should make sure that one byte will always be interpreted as one character. Still, a better approach would be storing the server response in an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBuffer) which is explicitly meant to deal with binary data.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open(...);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.send();

...

var array = new Uint8Array(request.response);
alert("First byte has value " + array[0]);
alert("Array length is " + array.length);
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), 
`responseType = "arraybuffer"` is supported starting with Chrome 10, Firefox 6 and Internet Explorer 10. See also: [Typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

*Side-note*: Firefox also supports `responseType = "moz-chunked-text"` and `responseType = "moz-chunked-arraybuffer"` starting with Firefox 9 which allow receiving data in chunks without resorting to ranged requests. It seems that Chrome doesn't plan to implement it, instead they are [working](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=240603) on implementing the [Streams API](http://www.w3.org/TR/streams-api/).

**Edit**: I was unable to reproduce your issue with Chrome lying to you about the response headers, at least not without your code. However, the code responsible should be this function in [partial_data.cc](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/http/partial_data.cc):

```c++
// We are making multiple requests to complete the range requested by the user.
// Just assume that everything is fine and say that we are returning what was
// requested.
void PartialData::FixResponseHeaders(HttpResponseHeaders* headers,
                                     bool success) {
  if (truncated_)
    return;

  if (byte_range_.IsValid() && success) {
    headers->UpdateWithNewRange(byte_range_, resource_size_, !sparse_entry_);
    return;
  }
```

This code will remove the `Content-Length` and `Content-Range` headers returned by the server and replace them by ones generated from your request parameters. Given that I cannot reproduce the issue myself, the following is only guesses:

- This code path seems to be used only for requests that can be satisfied from cache, so I guess that things will work correctly if you clear your cache.
- `resource_size_` variable must have a wrong value in your case, larger than the actual size of the requested file. This variable is determined from the `Content-Range` header in the first chunk requested, maybe you have a server response cached there which indicates a larger file.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! But the file is actually text (.csv), even though the server says it's `application/octet-stream`. Shouldn't matter because there are no bytes above 127 in the file anyway... what is mainly concerning to me is that the JavaScript call `xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")` does not match what the Network tab says for Content-Length. Is that a bug in Chrome? (It is the same in FF.)

Comment: @Matt: According to your screenshots, Firefox shows the correct value for content length. As to Chrome, I tend to distrust debuggers. What if you do `console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"))`?

Comment: (Right, sorry, I meant that FF appears to be correct.) The console.log line shows the same (incorrect) value in Chrome as the debugger.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for looking into that, and for digging into the Chromium source! These details will probably help me create a reproducible test case at least. That's a huge help.