# How does PapaParse stream from http?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, papaparse

The PapaParse CSV parser has a function to stream-parse over plain http:

```
Papa.parse("http://example.com/big.csv", {
    download: true,
    step: function(row) {
        console.log("Row:", row.data);
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log("All done!");
    }
});
```

I tried in the past to implement a stream parser in the browser via the `onprogress` event, but I found that browsers do not give access to `xhr.responseText` until the request has completed. How does PapaParse do this?

I would be really interested in a library or jQuery plugin that does this for plain text.

Comment: It's possible to see partial responses. See https://friendlybit.com/js/partial-xmlhttprequest-responses/

Comment: You are right, it does work. Not sure why this was not working before: http://jsfiddle.net/mfqdv2oy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Papa Parse uses the Range header to request specific bytes of a file, one piece at a time. I gave a [talk about this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vZE6AJ__I_yNLZDxdb5p33KeveWO2hc_ifaV792bUPw) on Friday at the UtahJS Conference. Although the presentation was more about loading files locally from disk, the same principle applies to remote files - merely the mechanism is different.

It's not too hard to implement yourself but be wary of [bugs in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745095/xmlhttprequest-and-chrome-developer-tools-dont-say-the-same-thing) if you happen to encounter that.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. Which event do you use for calling the parser? Would you ming making a minimal jsfiddle? Here is some CORS data I would like to parse line-by-line :) https://jeroenooms.github.io/data/diamonds.json

Comment: @Jeroen I assume you just use the normal `readystatechange` header. When you use the `Range` header, the response will be ready when the server has returned that portion of the file. So you just keep advanncing the range that you request.

Comment: @Jeroen It's a regular XHR request, but I add the Range HTTP header to the request and do this several times with a different byte range to iterate through the whole file.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I can't load csv in steps & getting the following error `Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Range"` can you tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @essaji Sounds like you're making a cross-origin request.

Comment: @Matt thank you for reply. Do you know, while using steps how can I also get the raw CSV text?